# JQuery textarea wont update after inputting value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So I have this textarea where it gets value from a .txt file, which works pretty good, but when I change the select option after inputting a new value in the textarea it wont update when the selected option is changed.

SCENARIO 1:
1. Change the  option, textarea updates (OK)

SCENARIO 2: (CAN'T UPDATE)
1. Change the  option
2. Input something in the textarea
3. Change the selected  option and the textarea wont update!

I have issued a mock JSFiddle for this. How could I update the textarea even after inputting something in the textarea?

http://jsfiddle.net/jxsew83L/1/

```
   <section class="content">
  <select name="select_template" id="select_template" class="form-control">
        <option count = '' content = ''>--Select--</option>
    <option count = '' content = 'CONTENT 1'>CONTENT 1</option>
    <option count = '' content = 'CONTENT 2'>CONTENT 2</option>
        </select>


  <div class="descriptionarea">
    <span style="padding: 5px;">Selected Clients <i class="fa fa-fw fa-eye"></i></span><br>
    <textarea id="text_content" name="text_content" rows="10" cols="60" title="" tabindex="0"></textarea><br>
    <span class="buttonfortxtarea"><button id = "btn_id" class= "btn btn-primary btn-flat" count = '' content = ''  filename = ''>SEND</button></span>
  </div>
</section>
```

and for the Jquery

```
     $(document).on("change", "#select_template", function(e) {
   var content = $('option:selected', this).attr('content');
   var count = $('option:selected', this).attr('count');
   var filename = $('option:selected', this).attr('filename');
   $(this).parent().parent().find('#text_content').html('');
   $(this).parent().parent().find('#text_content').value(content);

   $(this).parent().parent().find('#btn_id').attr('count', count);
   $(this).parent().parent().find('#btn_id').attr('filename', filename);


 });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your fiddle, changing the line

```
$(this).parent().parent().find('#text_content').html(content);
```

to

```
$(this).parent().parent().find('#text_content').val(content);
```

seems to fix the issue